# Google Sheets issue with literal constants in functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

When attempting to use any literal strings in formulas I get a `Formula parse error` and `#ERROR!` in the column with the formula.  For example:

```
=IF(D43=“x”,MULTIPLY(E42,2)).
```

I’ve been told that there is something wrong with the quote marks around the literal string `‘x’`. I am using an iPad keyboard.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apple devices, to get the CHAR(34) quote (i.e., "straight quote"), hold down the double-quote key on the keyboard. An alternatives popup will appear above. Slide your finger up into the alt menu and choose the straight quotes (usually far right).

Comment: Great. Happy to help. If you would, please mark my post as the best/correct answer. It helps everyone know at a glance which issues have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad keyboard is using the "typographic" quotation marks. Excel expects the "neutral" one.

That is `“` & `”` are not the same character as `"`. Not sure how to get around that on the iPad keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

## instead of `“ ”` use `" "` like: **`=IF(D43="x"; MULTIPLY(E42; 2))`**

- **if you don't have key for that on your keyboard you can press:** **<kbd>LEFT ALT</kbd>** + **<kbd>34</kbd>**
- **if you have an English keyboard then press:** **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** + **<kbd>'</kbd>** + **<kbd>'</kbd>**

  [image]
- **if you are on the touchscreen:**

  [image]